# python virtualenv -- possible to augment $PATH or add other environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

I'd like to alter my $PATH only in a Python virtual environment.  Is it possible to have the $PATH change when I activate a virtual environment?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I need access to a binary while in this environment, and would prefer not to permanently alter $PATH to get it.

Comment: @no_name - i do this to create a test environment. Activating the test environment starts by activating the virtualenv and then adding to the environment (and even mapping drives and running other programs). One stop shopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an activation script that sources virtualenv's activate (on linux, or calls the bat file on windows) and then updates PATH, PYTHONPATH and other environment variables. Use the virtualenv bootstrap hooks to install the script when the virtualenv is created and call it instead of `activate`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what operating system you are using you could edit the activate file and set an environment variable there.  For example, a Windows virtualenv folder has a sub-folder called Scripts.  Inside scripts is the activate.bat file.  Edit activate.bat and alter the path variable.  One thing to consider though, is you might want to save the original path variable in another temporary environment variable and restore from that temporary environment variable in the deactivate.bat file.